# @AuthenticationPrincipal does not fill fields from the base entity @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I need to get the current profile of an authorized user.

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '21'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc'

    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    // developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

There is a controller for this:

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Operation(summary = "Get user profile")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    @GetMapping(path = "/profile", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> profile(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        System.out.println("user.getId() = " + user.getId()); // always null
        return ResponseEntity.ok(mapper.map(user, UserDTO.class));
    }

}
```

console output always:
`user.getId() = null`

table `users`:

[image: table users]

`User`:

```java
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User extends BaseEntity<Integer> implements UserDetails {

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.email;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Role> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

`BaseEntity`:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<ID extends Serializable> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private ID id;

    // generated equals and hashCode with JPA Buddy ommited

}
```

I tried to get rid of `@MappedSuperclass`, removed inheritance from BaseEntity and created an id field by analogy from BaseEntity and everything worked as it should.
What could be the problem when using `@MappedSuperclass`?